# Low engine temp & slow oil life monitor - Thermostat?

Tags: temperature, acura, oil-life-indicator

2005 Acura RL

I noticed my oil life monitor was going incredibly slow, then also noticed the engine temp gauge seemed lower than it normally is.

I monitored the ODB-II when driving and it's running between 171° and 185°, well below normal engine operating temperatures. It got over 200° one day at idle, but that was just once that I noticed.

I figure the oil life is slow because of this. I'm almost at 7,000 miles and it says 60% healthy.

Is this a thermostat issue? I had one go out on my Camry years ago but when that happened, the engine temp completely bottomed out. This stays within that temp range.

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I don't think having a low temperature would cause the oil life indicator to slow down. The thermostat could be causing it to run low, however looking at what's available, it appears the "normal" thermostat for your vehicle is 170°F ... to me it appears your temp range is spot on the money for what it should be.